# How to map through array of objects and list each object in a card using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have the data structure like below,

```
const item = {
    id: '1',
    orders: [
        {
            id: '1',
            title: 'order-1',
            status: 'new',
            startDate: '2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z',
        }
    ],
    subItems: [
        {
            id: '1',
            title: 'subitem-one',
            status: 'new',
            startDate: '2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z',
            orders: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    title: 'subitem1-order-one',
                    status: 'new',
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'subitem1-order-two',
                    status: 'new',
                },
            ]
        },
  
        {
            id: '2',
            title: 'subitem-two',
            status: 'new',
            startDate: '2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z',
            orders: [
                {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'subitem2-order-one',
                    status: 'new',
                },
        },
```

I have to display each subitem name from above data in each card in a list.

below is how it should look in a list.

[image]

below is my code,

```
function Parent({items}: Props) {
    //items is the same data as mentioned above
    return (
        //how should i map the items data to loop through each subitem and display it as in the picture above.
    );
}
```

I am not sure how to loop through each subitem and display its name in a card using javascript and react.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: you missed to show how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, assuming that you are using `Card` component from material ui you could do something like:

```
import { Card, CardHeader} from '@material-ui/core';
function Parent({items}: Props) {
    //items is the same data as mentioned above
    return (
        items.subItems.map(el => {
          <Card>
            <CardHeader
                title={el.title}
            />
          </Card>
       })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Parent is a React functional component, so you can return the data in this way,

```
function Parent({items} : Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        items.subItems.map(function (subItem) {
          return <div>{subItem.title}</div>;
        });
      }
    </div>    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template is shown below:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const data = [...] // the data must be an array
  
  return data.map(child => <Child data={child} />)
}
```